# MYSQL Triggers New and OLD

Tags: mysql, database-trigger

How can I get the New/Old values from a table when using a trigger? I tried putting the previous population into another table and got an syntax error. I have edited the table and put the city/country schema so others can view and try to assist me.

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `world`$$

DROP TRIGGER /*!50032 IF EXISTS */ `previous_pop`$$

CREATE
    /*!50017 DEFINER = 'root'@'localhost' */
    TRIGGER `previous_pop` AFTER UPDATE ON city
    FOR country
    BEGIN
    previous.city_previous_pop = country.Old.Population;


    END;
$$

DELIMITER ;   

Error Code: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'country
    Begin
```

country schema;

```
TABLE_CATALOG   TABLE_SCHEMA    TABLE_NAME  COLUMN_NAME ORDINAL_POSITION    COLUMN_DEFAULT  IS_NULLABLE DATA_TYPE   CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH    CHARACTER_OCTET_LENGTH  NUMERIC_PRECISION   NUMERIC_SCALE   DATETIME_PRECISION  CHARACTER_SET_NAME  COLLATION_NAME  COLUMN_TYPE COLUMN_KEY  EXTRA   PRIVILEGES  COLUMN_COMMENT
def sakila  country country_id  1   \N  NO  smallint    \N  \N  5   0   \N  \N  \N  smallint(5) unsigned    PRI auto_increment  select,insert,update,references 
def sakila  country country 2   \N  NO  varchar 50  150 \N  \N  \N  utf8    utf8_general_ci varchar(50)         select,insert,update,references 
def sakila  country last_update 3   CURRENT_TIMESTAMP   NO  timestamp   \N  \N  \N  \N  0   \N  \N  timestamp       on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP select,insert,update,references 
def world   country Code    1       NO  char    3   3   \N  \N  \N  latin1  latin1_swedish_ci   char(3) PRI     select,insert,update,references 
def world   country Name    2       NO  char    52  52  \N  \N  \N  latin1  latin1_swedish_ci   char(52)            select,insert,update,references 
def world   country Continent   3   Asia    NO  enum    13  13  \N  \N  \N  latin1  latin1_swedish_ci   enum('Asia','Europe','North America','Africa','Oceania','Antarctica','South America')           select,insert,update,references 
def world   country Region  4       NO  char    26  26  \N  \N  \N  latin1  latin1_swedish_ci   char(26)            select,insert,update,references 
def world   country SurfaceArea 5   0.00    NO  float   \N  \N  10  2   \N  \N  \N  float(10,2)         select,insert,update,references 
def world   country IndepYear   6   \N  YES smallint    \N  \N  5   0   \N  \N  \N  smallint(6)         select,insert,update,references 
def world   country Population  7   0   NO  int \N  \N  10  0   \N  \N  \N  int(11)         select,insert,update,references 
def world   country LifeExpectancy  8   \N  YES float   \N  \N  3   1   \N  \N  \N  float(3,1)          select,insert,update,references 
def world   country GNP 9   \N  YES float   \N  \N  10  2   \N  \N  \N  float(10,2)         select,insert,update,references 
def world   country GNPOld  10  \N  YES float   \N  \N  10  2   \N  \N  \N  float(10,2)         select,insert,update,references 
def world   country LocalName   11      NO  char    45  45  \N  \N  \N  latin1  latin1_swedish_ci   char(45)            select,insert,update,references 
def world   country GovernmentForm  12      NO  char    45  45  \N  \N  \N  latin1  latin1_swedish_ci   char(45)            select,insert,update,references 
def world   country HeadOfState 13  \N  YES char    60  60  \N  \N  \N  latin1  latin1_swedish_ci   char(60)            select,insert,update,references 
def world   country Capital 14  \N  YES int \N  \N  10  0   \N  \N  \N  int(11)         select,insert,update,references 
def world   country Code2   15      NO  char    2   2   \N  \N  \N  latin1  latin1_swedish_ci   char(2)         select,insert,update,references
```

city schema:

```
TABLE_CATALOG   TABLE_SCHEMA    TABLE_NAME  COLUMN_NAME ORDINAL_POSITION    COLUMN_DEFAULT  IS_NULLABLE DATA_TYPE   CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH    CHARACTER_OCTET_LENGTH  NUMERIC_PRECISION   NUMERIC_SCALE   DATETIME_PRECISION  CHARACTER_SET_NAME  COLLATION_NAME  COLUMN_TYPE COLUMN_KEY  EXTRA   PRIVILEGES  COLUMN_COMMENT
def sakila  city    city_id 1   \N  NO  smallint    \N  \N  5   0   \N  \N  \N  smallint(5) unsigned    PRI auto_increment  select,insert,update,references 
def sakila  city    city    2   \N  NO  varchar 50  150 \N  \N  \N  utf8    utf8_general_ci varchar(50)         select,insert,update,references 
def sakila  city    country_id  3   \N  NO  smallint    \N  \N  5   0   \N  \N  \N  smallint(5) unsigned    MUL     select,insert,update,references 
def sakila  city    last_update 4   CURRENT_TIMESTAMP   NO  timestamp   \N  \N  \N  \N  0   \N  \N  timestamp       on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP select,insert,update,references 
def world   city    ID  1   \N  NO  int \N  \N  10  0   \N  \N  \N  int(11) PRI auto_increment  select,insert,update,references 
def world   city    Name    2       NO  char    35  35  \N  \N  \N  latin1  latin1_swedish_ci   char(35)            select,insert,update,references 
def world   city    CountryCode 3       NO  char    3   3   \N  \N  \N  latin1  latin1_swedish_ci   char(3)         select,insert,update,references 
def world   city    District    4       NO  char    20  20  \N  \N  \N  latin1  latin1_swedish_ci   char(20)            select,insert,update,references 
def world   city    Population  5   0   NO  int \N  \N  10  0   \N  \N  \N  int(11)         select,insert,update,references
```

After creating the trigger I ran this:

```
UPDATE city
SET Population = 1
WHERE CountryCode = 'AFG';

SELECT Population, CountryCode FROM city;

Population  CountryCode
1   AFG
1   AFG
1   AFG
1   AFG
```

And the country population did not change:

```
SELECT Population FROM country WHERE CODE = 'AFG';

Population
20387904
```

Comment: please share the complete `CREATE TRIGGER` statement, or at least a fully working (= failing) example. The error message does not match your query.

Comment: But, I do not understand how to acess an old or new data from the table what is the syntax? @Kaii

Comment: read this: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html

Comment: @âńōŋŷXmoůŜ, I have read that and I am a bit confused. I re-edited my post take a look.

Comment: Give us the columns in city and country. When city is updated, do you want the population in country to be updated too?

Comment: @âńōŋŷXmoůŜ, yes and, I wanted the old population and the new population after the update. And I am using the https://dev.mysql.com/doc/world-setup/en/ database. country.Population and City.Population

Comment: Can you copy/paste the schema of city and country on your post? Thanks.

Comment: @âńōŋŷXmoůŜ, I have edited the post please take a look! Is it possible that I should join the tables together then ill be able to do the .old and .new in an update?

Comment: @âńōŋŷXmoůŜ, thank you for teaching me what a schema was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the trigger to update country when there is an update on the city population.  Let say, Seoul city's population is updated from 10M to 11M; thus the country KOR population should also increase by 1M. The problem on your trigger is the syntax on "FOR country", and it should be "FOR EACH ROW". That is, for each row that is updated in city table, do an update on country table. The difference between the old city population and new city population will be added in the country population. If the city reduces the population then it will also subtract from the country population.

```
CREATE TRIGGER `previous_pop` AFTER UPDATE ON city
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN

      UPDATE country
      SET    Population = Population + (NEW.Population - OLD.Population)
      WHERE  Code = OLD.CountryCode;

    END;
```